# Como limitar o subscribe em apenas um loop

Tags: angular, typescript, router, eventos

Eu preciso exibir um alert toda vez que meu component principal muda de rota, então eu criei o seguinte script no meu `AppComponent`:

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {
      router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      alert(val);
    });
 }
```

Porem ele exibe o alert varias vezes, porem exibe o primeiro corretamente, tem como eu exibir apenas o primeiro valor do subscribe?e ignorar o resto? dando o alert apenas uma vez dentro do subscribe

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar o operador **take**

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html

```
  router.events.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((val) => {
      alert(val);
    });
```